# "Грамотнее" или "грамотней"

Tags: лексика

Контекст: Ребята, пишите грамотнее(ей)

Answer (score 7):

Это равноправные варианты. Мне кажется, что в письменном варианте  предпочтительней суффикс ЕЕ. В устной речи (и в письменной, передающей устную речь) - ЕЙ. Но это моё  мнение, соответствующего утверждения в справочниках не нашла. Разве что косвенные признаки:везде пишут об образовании сравнительной степени с помощью суффиксов ЕЕ(ЕЙ), а примеры рядом приводят в основном с ЕЙ. Хотя есть и из Твардовского: *Как-то все дружней и строже, как-то все тебе дороже. И родней, чем час назад*